# Trying to create a routing map in python using folium and json and it is failing on the creating of the json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, folium

I am trying to create map using using a tutorial here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-plot-a-route-on-a-map-fb900a7f6605

I'm using a different API source from the tutorial (since I'm just trying it out, I don't want to pay yet per use). I don't think it should be causing the problem

```
def get_lat_from_address(address):
    loc = Nominatim(user_agent = "Geopy Library")
    getLoc = loc.geocode(address)
    return getLoc.latitude

def get_long_from_address(address):
    loc = Nominatim(user_agent = "Geopy Library")
    getLoc = loc.geocode(address)
    return getLoc.longitude
```

```
def get_directions_response(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, mode = 'drive'):
    url = "https://trueway-directions2.p.rapidapi.com/FindDrivingRoute"
    key = "ee0c421288msh0d6e2496d005d6fp1d0a17jsnbcff9489b621"
    host= "trueway-directions2.p.rapidapi.com"
    headers = {"X-RapidAPI-Key": key, "X-RapidAPI-Host": host}
    querystring = {"stops":f"{str(lat1)},{str(long1)}|{str(lat2)},{str(long2)}","mode":mode}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params = querystring)
    return response
```

```
response = get_directions_response(get_lat_from_address("Carrollton 75010"), 
                        get_long_from_address("Carrollton 75010"),
                        get_lat_from_address("Frisco 75034"),
                        get_long_from_address("Frisco 75034"))
```

^^ This is the parred down addresses for privacy reasons, but it works with any address.

```
def create_map(response):
    
    json_data = response.json()
    print(json_data)
    mls = response.json()['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
    points = [(i[1], i[0]) for i in mls[0]]
    
    m = folium.Map()
    
    # add marker for the start and ending points
    
    for point in [points[0], points[-1]]:
        folium.Marker(point).add_to(m)
   
    # add the lines
    folium.PolyLine(points, weight=5, opacity=1).add_to(m)

    # create optimal zoom
   
    df = pd.DataFrame(mls[0]).rename(columns={0:'Lon', 1:'Lat'})[['Lat', 'Lon']]
    sw = df[['Lat', 'Lon']].min().values.tolist()
    ne = df[['Lat', 'Lon']].max().values.tolist()
    m.fit_bounds([sw, ne])
   
    return m
```

when I enter the following:

m = create_map(response)

I get this:

```
{'route': {'distance': 18538, 'duration': 906, 'bounds': {'south': 33.010557, 'west': -96.942534, 'north': 33.108205, 'east': -96.82042}, 'geometry': {'coordinates': [[33.016078, -96.933534], [33.016058, -96.933732], [33.016029, -96.933889], [33.01594, -96.934244], [33.015842, -96.934441], [33.015793, -96.93452], [33.015675, -96.934677], [33.015507, -96.934854], [33.01531, -96.935022], [33.014944, -96.935308], [33.014447, -96.935644], [33.014207, -96.935822], [33.013745, -96.936119], [33.013644, -96.936179], [33.013564, -96.936209], [33.013523, -96.936219], [33.013271, -96.936288], [33.012956, -96.936328], [33.012723, -96.936338], [33.01255, -96.936378], [33.012418, -96.936428], [33.012173, -96.936538], [33.012102, -96.936587], [33.01201, -96.936647], [33.011857, -96.936797], [33.011735, -96.936938], [33.011725, -96.936958], [33.011654, -96.937048], [33.011562, -96.937189], [33.011409, -96.93749], [33.011226, -96.937864], [33.011145, -96.938056], [33.011054, -96.938249], [33.010902, -96.938594], [33.010881, -96.938634], [33.01081, -96.938827], [33.01077, -96.938949], [33.010739, -96.93903], [33.010669, -96.939274], [33.010608, -96.939558], [33.010598, -96.93966], [33.010578, -96.939761], [33.010557, -96.939994], [33.010557, -96.940126], [33.010557, -96.940257], [33.010557, -96.940479], [33.010568, -96.94059], [33.010588, -96.940701], [33.010658, -96.941102], [33.010679, -96.941233], [33.01077, -96.941492], [33.010851, -96.941652], [33.010912, -96.941771], [33.011013, -96.94191], [33.011155, -96.942099], [33.011308, -96.942287], [33.011318, -96.942297], [33.011399, -96.942406], [33.011409, -96.942426], [33.011511, -96.942455], [33.011552, -96.942485], [33.011593, -96.942495], [33.011623, -96.942515], [33.011664, -96.942524], [33.011705, -96.942524], [33.011745, -96.942534], [33.011776, -96.942524], [33.011888, -96.942495], [33.012092, -96.942277], [33.012214, -96.942148], [33.012306, -96.942049], [33.012438, -96.94192], [33.012692, -96.941682], [33.012713, -96.941662], [33.013007, -96.941393], [33.013291, -96.941133], [33.013584, -96.940872], [33.013624, -96.940832], [33.013725, -96.940741], [33.014087, -96.940399], [33.014387, -96.940116], [33.014517, -96.939994], [33.014636, -96.939883], [33.014795, -96.939721], [33.014805, -96.939721], [33.014815, -96.939721], [33.014944, -96.939711], [33.015419, -96.939254], [33.015606, -96.939081], [33.015754, -96.938949], [33.015852, -96.938868], [33.015881, -96.938837], [33.01599, -96.938746], [33.016117, -96.938634], [33.016274, -96.938502], [33.016431, -96.938371], [33.016539, -96.938289], [33.016667, -96.938188], [33.016922, -96.937996], [33.016971, -96.937955], [33.01706, -96.937884], [33.017187, -96.937793], [33.018115, -96.937108], [33.018245, -96.937028], [33.018743, -96.936677], [33.018813, -96.936627], [33.019084, -96.936438], [33.019648, -96.93604], [33.020613, -96.935347], [33.020939, -96.93518], [33.021285, -96.934943], [33.021469, -96.934815], [33.02156, -96.934746], [33.021641, -96.934697], [33.021743, -96.934618], [33.021926, -96.9345], [33.022068, -96.934402], [33.022301, -96.934234], [33.022382, -96.934185], [33.022594, -96.934027], [33.022695, -96.933958], [33.022785, -96.933889], [33.022886, -96.93382], [33.023077, -96.933692], [33.023277, -96.933544], [33.023387, -96.933465], [33.023477, -96.933406], [33.023666, -96.933277], [33.023785, -96.933188], [33.023865, -96.933129], [33.023954, -96.933069], [33.024053, -96.93299], [33.024152, -96.93292], [33.024251, -96.932851], [33.02435, -96.932781], [33.024498, -96.932672], [33.024724, -96.932512], [33.024921, -96.932363], [33.025107, -96.932223], [33.025294, -96.932092], [33.025392, -96.932022], [33.025578, -96.931882], [33.025863, -96.931671], [33.026138, -96.931469], [33.026433, -96.931257], [33.026818, -96.930974], [33.026888, -96.930923], [33.027016, -96.930822], [33.027036, -96.930812], [33.027493, -96.930477], [33.027913, -96.930173], [33.028205, -96.929959], [33.028608, -96.929665], [33.02881, -96.929523], [33.029115, -96.9293], [33.029206, -96.929239], [33.029308, -96.929168], [33.02942, -96.929087], [33.029623, -96.928945], [33.029694, -96.928884], [33.029827, -96.928793], [33.029929, -96.928723], [33.030112, -96.928591], [33.030397, -96.92839], [33.030591, -96.928249], [33.030794, -96.928108], [33.031088, -96.927898], [33.031372, -96.927697], [33.031564, -96.927558], [33.031644, -96.927508], [33.031856, -96.927348], [33.031956, -96.927278], [33.032147, -96.927149], [33.032317, -96.92702], [33.032606, -96.926822], [33.032895, -96.926614], [33.032934, -96.926584], [33.033093, -96.926466], [33.03329, -96.926327], [33.033478, -96.926189], [33.033537, -96.92615], [33.033862, -96.925913], [33.03397, -96.925845], [33.034333, -96.925579], [33.034735, -96.925283], [33.034834, -96.925215], [33.034932, -96.925146], [33.03503, -96.925077], [33.035119, -96.925018], [33.035217, -96.924939], [33.035345, -96.92485], [33.035888, -96.924465], [33.036096, -96.924307], [33.036175, -96.924257], [33.036294, -96.924168], [33.036493, -96.92403], [33.036683, -96.923891], [33.036803, -96.923821], [33.036893, -96.923761], [33.037004, -96.923692], [33.037094, -96.923642], [33.037184, -96.923582], [33.037295, -96.923522], [33.037335, -96.923502], [33.037396, -96.923472], [33.037497, -96.923423], [33.037618, -96.923363], [33.037719, -96.923323], [33.037851, -96.923263], [33.037952, -96.923223], [33.038064, -96.923183], [33.038176, -96.923143], [33.038287, -96.923102], [33.038399, -96.923062], [33.038511, -96.923032], [33.038613, -96.923002], [33.038664, -96.922992], [33.038735, -96.922972], [33.038847, -96.922942], [33.038969, -96.922922], [33.039082, -96.922892], [33.039204, -96.922872], [33.039316, -96.922852], [33.039428, -96.922832], [33.03954, -96.922822], [33.039662, -96.922811], [33.039774, -96.922801], [33.039885, -96.922791], [33.040007, -96.922781], [33.040068, -96.922781], [33.040119, -96.922781], [33.04024, -96.922781], [33.040342, -96.922781], [33.040453, -96.922781], [33.040564, -96.922791], [33.040675, -96.922791], [33.040926, -96.922801], [33.041157, -96.922811], [33.041377, -96.922822], [33.041626, -96.922832], [33.041845, -96.922842], [33.042053, -96.922852], [33.042379, -96.922862], [33.042596, -96.922872], [33.042763, -96.922872], [33.042921, -96.922882], [33.043137, -96.922892], [33.043353, -96.922902], [33.043569, -96.922912], [33.043775, -96.922912], [33.043804, -96.922912], [33.044001, -96.922922], [33.044109, -96.922912], [33.044207, -96.922912], [33.044286, -96.922912], [33.044404, -96.922912], [33.044424, -96.922902], [33.044522, -96.922902], [33.044631, -96.922892], [33.044739, -96.922882], [33.044769, -96.922882], [33.044848, -96.922872], [33.044957, -96.922862], [33.045036, -96.922852], [33.045165, -96.922832], [33.045274, -96.922822], [33.045384, -96.922801], [33.045493, -96.922781], [33.045603, -96.922761], [33.045743, -96.922741], [33.046024, -96.922671], [33.046044, -96.922671], [33.046235, -96.92262], [33.046356, -96.92259], [33.0468, -96.922449], [33.047003, -96.922378], [33.047094, -96.922348], [33.047115, -96.922338], [33.047318, -96.922257], [33.047348, -96.922247], [33.04742, -96.922217], [33.04744, -96.922217], [33.04746, -96.922207], [33.047542, -96.922166], [33.047562, -96.922156], [33.047654, -96.922126], [33.047674, -96.922106], [33.047735, -96.922085], [33.047755, -96.922075], [33.047847, -96.922035], [33.047868, -96.922025], [33.047949, -96.921984], [33.047969, -96.921974], [33.048051, -96.921934], [33.048173, -96.921873], [33.048245, -96.921832], [33.048265, -96.921822], [33.048357, -96.921771], [33.048377, -96.921761], [33.048458, -96.921721], [33.048479, -96.921711], [33.04855, -96.92166], [33.04857, -96.92165], [33.048652, -96.921609], [33.048672, -96.921589], [33.048743, -96.921548], [33.048763, -96.921538], [33.048845, -96.921487], [33.048865, -96.921477], [33.048946, -96.921427], [33.048967, -96.921406], [33.049048, -96.921366], [33.049068, -96.921345], [33.049139, -96.921295], [33.049159, -96.921274], [33.04923, -96.921234], [33.04925, -96.921213], [33.049331, -96.921163], [33.049352, -96.921152], [33.049422, -96.921102], [33.049443, -96.921081], [33.049513, -96.92103], [33.049533, -96.92101], [33.049614, -96.920959], [33.049634, -96.920939], [33.049695, -96.920888], [33.049916, -96.920705], [33.049976, -96.920655], [33.050047, -96.920594], [33.050247, -96.920411], [33.050437, -96.920229], [33.050497, -96.920168], [33.050586, -96.920077], [33.050666, -96.919996], [33.050765, -96.919884], [33.051053, -96.919581], [33.051083, -96.919551], [33.051132, -96.919501], [33.051211, -96.91941], [33.051369, -96.919239], [33.051389, -96.919209], [33.051596, -96.918968], [33.051606, -96.918948], [33.051675, -96.918857], [33.051754, -96.918757], [33.051823, -96.918657], [33.051891, -96.918568], [33.05199, -96.918438], [33.052107, -96.918259], [33.052166, -96.918169], [33.052304, -96.917951], [33.052372, -96.917861], [33.052422, -96.917782], [33.05249, -96.917654], [33.052539, -96.917574], [33.052618, -96.917436], [33.052745, -96.917199], [33.052794, -96.917101], [33.052863, -96.916982], [33.052912, -96.916874], [33.052971, -96.916766], [33.05303, -96.916648], [33.05305, -96.916598], [33.053079, -96.91653], [33.053177, -96.916323], [33.053237, -96.916195], [33.053286, -96.916087], [33.053335, -96.915968], [33.053394, -96.91585], [33.053493, -96.915633], [33.053542, -96.915515], [33.053621, -96.915356], [33.053749, -96.915059], [33.053848, -96.914841], [33.053897, -96.914731], [33.053927, -96.914672], [33.053957, -96.914602], [33.054026, -96.914452], [33.054056, -96.914383], [33.054155, -96.914153], [33.054264, -96.913912], [33.054304, -96.913822], [33.054414, -96.91357], [33.054523, -96.913318], [33.054613, -96.913106], [33.054663, -96.912974], [33.054763, -96.912751], [33.054853, -96.912528], [33.054963, -96.912274], [33.054983, -96.912223], [33.055114, -96.911929], [33.055164, -96.911817], [33.055376, -96.91135], [33.055507, -96.911046], [33.055638, -96.910773], [33.0558, -96.91042], [33.055902, -96.910178], [33.056003, -96.909978], [33.056115, -96.909727], [33.056328, -96.909269], [33.056593, -96.908703], [33.056745, -96.908367], [33.056786, -96.908288], [33.056857, -96.90814], [33.056908, -96.908022], [33.057122, -96.907569], [33.057245, -96.907313], [33.057336, -96.907126], [33.057438, -96.906899], [33.05757, -96.906623], [33.057703, -96.906337], [33.057855, -96.906], [33.057875, -96.90596], [33.057926, -96.905841], [33.057936, -96.905831], [33.05818, -96.905303], [33.05823, -96.905193], [33.058291, -96.905062], [33.058311, -96.905012], [33.058392, -96.904842], [33.058443, -96.904721], [33.058483, -96.904651], [33.058594, -96.904399], [33.059197, -96.903051], [33.059626, -96.902097], [33.059855, -96.901591], [33.059924, -96.90143], [33.059994, -96.901269], [33.060063, -96.901118], [33.060132, -96.900968], [33.060261, -96.900677], [33.06034, -96.900488], [33.060419, -96.900328], [33.060468, -96.900219], [33.060576, -96.89997], [33.060872, -96.899318], [33.06096, -96.89912], [33.060999, -96.899051], [33.061137, -96.898736], [33.061157, -96.898697], [33.061284, -96.8985], [33.061441, -96.898234], [33.06152, -96.898077], [33.061637, -96.89783], [33.061667, -96.897771], [33.061785, -96.897495], [33.061902, -96.897257], [33.061961, -96.897109], [33.06203, -96.89696], [33.062128, -96.896741], [33.062158, -96.896662], [33.062207, -96.896562], [33.062374, -96.896153], [33.062404, -96.896082], [33.062473, -96.895922], [33.062532, -96.895751], [33.062581, -96.89564], [33.062719, -96.895308], [33.062759, -96.895207], [33.062808, -96.895075], [33.062868, -96.894944], [33.062937, -96.894771], [33.062987, -96.89465], [33.063066, -96.894457], [33.063096, -96.894376], [33.063404, -96.893655], [33.063583, -96.893249], [33.063773, -96.892814], [33.063933, -96.89246], [33.064094, -96.892098], [33.064225, -96.891797], [33.064235, -96.891787], [33.064295, -96.891657], [33.064578, -96.89103], [33.064648, -96.890891], [33.064739, -96.890693], [33.064841, -96.890466], [33.064942, -96.890249], [33.065023, -96.890091], [33.065206, -96.889707], [33.065247, -96.889608], [33.065359, -96.889362], [33.06547, -96.889136], [33.065674, -96.888702], [33.065715, -96.888613], [33.065806, -96.888426], [33.065827, -96.888376], [33.065847, -96.888327], [33.065878, -96.888257], [33.065908, -96.888198], [33.065939, -96.888109], [33.06602, -96.88794], [33.066051, -96.887871], [33.066102, -96.887771], [33.066122, -96.887722], [33.066204, -96.887552], [33.066316, -96.887313], [33.066418, -96.887092], [33.066479, -96.886962], [33.06658, -96.886741], [33.066692, -96.886499], [33.066753, -96.886368], [33.066794, -96.886257], [33.066875, -96.886095], [33.067078, -96.88565], [33.067382, -96.88497], [33.067443, -96.884837], [33.067564, -96.884573], [33.067745, -96.884158], [33.067936, -96.883743], [33.068287, -96.882968], [33.068367, -96.882807], [33.068457, -96.882597], [33.068477, -96.882558], [33.068497, -96.882528], [33.068596, -96.882308], [33.068646, -96.882209], [33.068676, -96.882139], [33.068736, -96.88202], [33.068775, -96.881921], [33.068845, -96.881782], [33.069004, -96.881466], [33.069004, -96.881456], [33.069053, -96.881367], [33.069083, -96.881308], [33.069132, -96.881209], [33.069152, -96.88117], [33.06932, -96.880854], [33.06934, -96.880805], [33.069369, -96.880756], [33.069478, -96.880539], [33.069537, -96.880421], [33.069616, -96.880274], [33.069685, -96.880136], [33.069704, -96.880106], [33.069823, -96.87988], [33.070049, -96.879445], [33.070157, -96.879218], [33.070274, -96.879], [33.070333, -96.878871], [33.070569, -96.878353], [33.070745, -96.877962], [33.070942, -96.87752], [33.071364, -96.876589], [33.071424, -96.876437], [33.071769, -96.875655], [33.071848, -96.875472], [33.072603, -96.873797], [33.072853, -96.873239], [33.073094, -96.872713], [33.073144, -96.872604], [33.073184, -96.872515], [33.073861, -96.871057], [33.074237, -96.870277], [33.074318, -96.870089], [33.075173, -96.868227], [33.075418, -96.86769], [33.07556, -96.867396], [33.075774, -96.866909], [33.075804, -96.866827], [33.075855, -96.866716], [33.075987, -96.866452], [33.07618, -96.866016], [33.076331, -96.865672], [33.076453, -96.86542], [33.076624, -96.865038], [33.076665, -96.864928], [33.076856, -96.864518], [33.077317, -96.863515], [33.077556, -96.863002], [33.077746, -96.862579], [33.078192, -96.861613], [33.07836, -96.861238], [33.07836, -96.861228], [33.078409, -96.861139], [33.079107, -96.85956], [33.079245, -96.859257], [33.079323, -96.859085], [33.079343, -96.859025], [33.079372, -96.858964], [33.079451, -96.858792], [33.07948, -96.858721], [33.079637, -96.858366], [33.079686, -96.858254], [33.079814, -96.857949], [33.079971, -96.857604], [33.080128, -96.857229], [33.080168, -96.857158], [33.080217, -96.857026], [33.080453, -96.856511], [33.080473, -96.85646], [33.08065, -96.856068], [33.080818, -96.855677], [33.080996, -96.855288], [33.081394, -96.854416], [33.081803, -96.85352], [33.082114, -96.852801], [33.082215, -96.852584], [33.082396, -96.852139], [33.082608, -96.851632], [33.083023, -96.85054], [33.083226, -96.849984], [33.083359, -96.849619], [33.083409, -96.849467], [33.08345, -96.849355], [33.083572, -96.84898], [33.083593, -96.848939], [33.083776, -96.84836], [33.084143, -96.847209], [33.084214, -96.846968], [33.084326, -96.846607], [33.084448, -96.846169], [33.08453, -96.845871], [33.084682, -96.845357], [33.084784, -96.844992], [33.084824, -96.844864], [33.084824, -96.844835], [33.084865, -96.844717], [33.084885, -96.844638], [33.084916, -96.84452], [33.084997, -96.844234], [33.085078, -96.843968], [33.085139, -96.843761], [33.08519, -96.843594], [33.085291, -96.843228], [33.085554, -96.842283], [33.085614, -96.842072], [33.085735, -96.841671], [33.085866, -96.841166], [33.085876, -96.841136], [33.086047, -96.840518], [33.086227, -96.839837], [33.086277, -96.839675], [33.086367, -96.83936], [33.086407, -96.839218], [33.086586, -96.838551], [33.086726, -96.838038], [33.086865, -96.837518], [33.087112, -96.836634], [33.087063, -96.836436], [33.087063, -96.836426], [33.087152, -96.836012], [33.087162, -96.835953], [33.087192, -96.835805], [33.087241, -96.835618], [33.087271, -96.83547], [33.08732, -96.835244], [33.087379, -96.834968], [33.087419, -96.834791], [33.087488, -96.834475], [33.087488, -96.834445], [33.087507, -96.834356], [33.087527, -96.834257], [33.087576, -96.834049], [33.087616, -96.833881], [33.087636, -96.833761], [33.087655, -96.833662], [33.087665, -96.833622], [33.087685, -96.833552], [33.087714, -96.833413], [33.087744, -96.833263], [33.087773, -96.833122], [33.087773, -96.833072], [33.087773, -96.833032], [33.087763, -96.832992], [33.087744, -96.832922], [33.088098, -96.831518], [33.088225, -96.831], [33.088235, -96.83098], [33.088284, -96.830766], [33.088461, -96.830097], [33.088549, -96.829773], [33.088794, -96.828847], [33.088873, -96.828538], [33.088961, -96.828189], [33.089069, -96.827792], [33.089119, -96.827624], [33.089374, -96.826608], [33.089562, -96.826027], [33.089631, -96.82583], [33.089749, -96.825524], [33.089888, -96.825158], [33.089987, -96.8249], [33.090096, -96.824592], [33.090145, -96.824432], [33.090314, -96.823822], [33.090334, -96.823691], [33.090364, -96.8236], [33.090414, -96.823318], [33.090463, -96.823045], [33.090473, -96.823015], [33.090513, -96.822842], [33.090513, -96.822812], [33.090573, -96.822508], [33.090823, -96.822508], [33.090913, -96.822498], [33.090923, -96.822498], [33.090933, -96.822498], [33.090943, -96.822498], [33.090963, -96.822498], [33.090973, -96.822498], [33.091004, -96.822498], [33.091154, -96.822498], [33.091285, -96.822487], [33.091356, -96.822487], [33.091366, -96.822487], [33.0918, -96.822487], [33.091841, -96.822487], [33.091851, -96.822487], [33.091861, -96.822487], [33.092094, -96.822467], [33.092216, -96.822467], [33.092521, -96.822467], [33.093316, -96.822467], [33.094038, -96.822467], [33.094048, -96.822467], [33.094594, -96.822457], [33.094735, -96.822447], [33.095127, -96.822437], [33.095217, -96.822437], [33.095865, -96.822437], [33.096093, -96.822437], [33.096507, -96.822457], [33.097029, -96.822457], [33.097461, -96.822447], [33.09804, -96.822447], [33.098433, -96.822437], [33.098443, -96.822437], [33.09867, -96.822437], [33.098838, -96.822447], [33.098848, -96.822447], [33.099026, -96.822437], [33.099563, -96.822427], [33.099583, -96.822427], [33.099693, -96.822427], [33.100305, -96.822396], [33.100669, -96.822376], [33.100679, -96.822376], [33.101094, -96.822366], [33.101145, -96.822355], [33.101196, -96.822355], [33.10147, -96.822345], [33.101898, -96.822345], [33.102082, -96.822345], [33.102418, -96.822335], [33.102784, -96.822325], [33.102946, -96.822325], [33.103088, -96.822325], [33.103735, -96.822345], [33.104167, -96.822345], [33.104217, -96.822345], [33.104507, -96.822345], [33.104726, -96.822355], [33.105013, -96.822376], [33.105083, -96.822386], [33.105152, -96.822386], [33.105231, -96.822396], [33.105478, -96.822427], [33.105488, -96.822427], [33.105586, -96.822447], [33.105911, -96.822518], [33.106196, -96.822599], [33.106255, -96.822619], [33.106274, -96.822619], [33.106549, -96.822721], [33.106549, -96.822071], [33.106539, -96.821665], [33.106549, -96.8213], [33.106598, -96.820601], [33.106804, -96.820601], [33.10701, -96.820652], [33.107069, -96.820662], [33.107227, -96.820692], [33.107345, -96.820723], [33.107424, -96.820733], [33.107463, -96.820743], [33.107581, -96.820773], [33.107591, -96.820773], [33.107621, -96.820632], [33.10767, -96.820642], [33.1077, -96.820652], [33.107719, -96.820652], [33.108205, -96.820632], [33.108205, -96.82042]]}, 'legs': [{'distance': 18538, 'duration': 906, 'start_point_index': 0, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.016078, 'lng': -96.933534}, 'end_point_index': 783, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.108205, 'lng': -96.82042}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.010557, 'west': -96.942534, 'north': 33.108205, 'east': -96.82042}, 'steps': [{'distance': 1186, 'duration': 86, 'start_point_index': 0, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.016078, 'lng': -96.933534}, 'end_point_index': 58, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.011409, 'lng': -96.942426}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.010557, 'west': -96.942426, 'north': 33.016078, 'east': -96.933534}}, {'distance': 484, 'duration': 34, 'start_point_index': 58, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.011409, 'lng': -96.942426}, 'end_point_index': 86, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.014944, 'lng': -96.939711}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.011409, 'west': -96.942534, 'north': 33.014944, 'east': -96.939711}, 'maneuver': 'ramp right'}, {'distance': 448, 'duration': 15, 'start_point_index': 86, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.014944, 'lng': -96.939711}, 'end_point_index': 103, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.018245, 'lng': -96.937028}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.014944, 'west': -96.939711, 'north': 33.018245, 'east': -96.937028}, 'maneuver': 'merge'}, {'distance': 12840, 'duration': 416, 'start_point_index': 103, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.018245, 'lng': -96.937028}, 'end_point_index': 638, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.087112, 'lng': -96.836634}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.018245, 'west': -96.937028, 'north': 33.087112, 'east': -96.836634}}, {'distance': 362, 'duration': 15, 'start_point_index': 638, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.087112, 'lng': -96.836634}, 'end_point_index': 665, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.087744, 'lng': -96.832922}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.087063, 'west': -96.836634, 'north': 33.087773, 'east': -96.832922}, 'maneuver': 'ramp right'}, {'distance': 136, 'duration': 7, 'start_point_index': 665, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.087744, 'lng': -96.832922}, 'end_point_index': 666, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.088098, 'lng': -96.831518}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.087744, 'west': -96.832922, 'north': 33.088098, 'east': -96.831518}, 'maneuver': 'merge'}, {'distance': 888, 'duration': 88, 'start_point_index': 666, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.088098, 'lng': -96.831518}, 'end_point_index': 693, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.090573, 'lng': -96.822508}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.088098, 'west': -96.831518, 'north': 33.090573, 'east': -96.822508}}, {'distance': 1259, 'duration': 104, 'start_point_index': 693, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.090573, 'lng': -96.822508}, 'end_point_index': 742, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.101898, 'lng': -96.822345}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.090573, 'west': -96.822508, 'north': 33.101898, 'east': -96.822345}, 'maneuver': 'turn left'}, {'distance': 523, 'duration': 64, 'start_point_index': 742, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.101898, 'lng': -96.822345}, 'end_point_index': 764, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.106549, 'lng': -96.822721}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.101898, 'west': -96.822721, 'north': 33.106549, 'east': -96.822325}}, {'distance': 196, 'duration': 20, 'start_point_index': 764, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.106549, 'lng': -96.822721}, 'end_point_index': 768, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.106598, 'lng': -96.820601}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.106539, 'west': -96.822721, 'north': 33.106598, 'east': -96.820601}, 'maneuver': 'turn right'}, {'distance': 115, 'duration': 23, 'start_point_index': 768, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.106598, 'lng': -96.820601}, 'end_point_index': 777, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.107591, 'lng': -96.820773}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.106598, 'west': -96.820773, 'north': 33.107591, 'east': -96.820601}, 'maneuver': 'turn left'}, {'distance': 15, 'duration': 5, 'start_point_index': 777, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.107591, 'lng': -96.820773}, 'end_point_index': 778, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.107621, 'lng': -96.820632}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.107591, 'west': -96.820773, 'north': 33.107621, 'east': -96.820632}, 'maneuver': 'turn right'}, {'distance': 66, 'duration': 18, 'start_point_index': 778, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.107621, 'lng': -96.820632}, 'end_point_index': 782, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.108205, 'lng': -96.820632}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.107621, 'west': -96.820652, 'north': 33.108205, 'east': -96.820632}, 'maneuver': 'turn left'}, {'distance': 20, 'duration': 11, 'start_point_index': 782, 'start_point': {'lat': 33.108205, 'lng': -96.820632}, 'end_point_index': 783, 'end_point': {'lat': 33.108205, 'lng': -96.82042}, 'bounds': {'south': 33.108205, 'west': -96.820632, 'north': 33.108205, 'east': -96.82042}, 'maneuver': 'turn right'}]}]}}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[57], line 1
----> 1 m = create_map(response)

Cell In[56], line 5, in create_map(response)
      3 json_data = response.json()
      4 print(json_data)
----> 5 mls = response.json()['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
      6 points = [(i[1], i[0]) for i in mls[0]]
      8 m = folium.Map()

KeyError: 'features'
```

According to the website I'm using as a reference it should look something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKCOc.png)

It looks like my code is missing the JSON hierarchies for it be completely compatible.

I don't really work with JSONs all that much, so how would I fix this issue in python so it produces some sort of image?

Outlined above in my question is my solution.

Comment: The error makes clear that the `response.json()` does not contain a `'features'` field. You can try printing what `response.json()` is to see the format of your data.

Comment: you could also print `response.json().keys()`

Comment: you said you use `different API` - so you should expect `different results`

Comment: you run `print(json_data)` and you should see that it uses `json_data['route']['geometry']['coordinates']`. BTW: you can use module `pprint` (PrettyPrint) to display JSON in better formatted form - and you will see what keys you need. You may also use `type(json_data)` to check if you have `dict` or `list` and use `.keys()` or `[0]` to get nested elements - like `json_data['route']` - and later again `type( json_data['route'] )` and again use `.keys()` or `[0]`, etc.

Comment: eventually you may write function which will use recursion to search key `coordinates` in all structure.